# Where is the SQL persistent store created by CoreData?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Can someone help me find where CoreData is storing the SQL file it creates in iOS applications?

So far I've tried "Show package contents" on the .xcdatamodel file and also the .xcodeproj file...No dice!

Is there an editor for looking at the contents of these SQL files?

Cheers.

-A

Answer (score 1):

The `url` parameter of `[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:url:options:error]` specifies the location of the file.  Find this call in your code and see where you've stored it. XCode templates will put it into the top of your application documents directory, but you can put it anywhere you like.

Note that Apple considers the contents of this database to be opaque and non-user-modifiable. Playing with the data in your store is likely to cause issues with Core Data.

Comment: I know where the code tells the file to be saved. My issue is actually finding the applications documents directory. If you run it in the simulator it's stored somewhere on my mac and when I run it on my iPhone it's stored somewhere there. How do you determine the sequence folders to click on using the url that sets the location of the SQL store?

Answer (score 0):

It's typically saved into your application's documents directory, with the name of your data model.

So, for example, if my data model is called *AppData.xcdatamodeld*, it will be AppData.sqlite inside my app's document directory. You shouldn't really need to touch the .sqlite file though.

Hope that helps!

Comment: How do you find the applications documents directory on the simulator and on the iPhone?

Answer (score -1):

Core Data editor --> http://christian-kienle.de/CoreDataEditor/